# Is it possible to create an object on a background thread with no reference on the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

Equities trading application uses a class library for getting callbacks on stock quote updates, another class library for getting callbacks on order executions or cancelations. I currently have the callbacks execute in the thread pool. I start one background thread for each callback. The threads are very short lived and the work involved includes fetching the data and notifying the observers. Once observers are notified the background thread dies. When I have strategies subscribing to over 1000 actively traded symbols I get OutOfMemory exceptions.

How can I improve this design? I was thinking of starting two threads at the start, one for quotes, the other for executions, and creating each object on its respective threads. Then just have a shared object which allows adding and removing observers to the threads. But 1) how would you keep the thread alive to receive the callbacks? 2) How can you even have a callback object which is initialized on a thread with no reference on the main thread? Is this even possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [producer / consumer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) model with a simple queue. Then you have a set number of worker threads running and you won't have this problem.

As for *how* to call the callback function, you could possibly use a struct like this:

```
struct WorkerData
{
    Data data;
    Delegate someCallback;
}
```

when the worker is finished with the data it can invoke the callback itself.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so this would solve my OutOfMemory exception. I'll have to test the timeliness as the system can't afford a millisecond of delay. Is there a way to initialize the class library i'm using on the thread and make it live there? This was my other question.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure this is possible. At the start of the thread's execution (before the consumer loop), initialize it once and use it after that. Should make things pretty zippy.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is a general picture of your application.  In order to redesign your application we concrete requirements and at least a simplified model of how the participants interact with each other.  Your informal description is not precise enough to suggest a specific data structure and algorithm because without knowing all enough details we might omit something crucial and not meet your needs.

You are saying all the right words and you have a specific problem, out of memory, and you need to fix something.  Go back to prototyping.  Write a very small but brutally exercised program to demonstrate what you want to do.  Then scale it back up to your application.  It's much easier to design in the prototype size.

**Edit:**

Because you are running out of memory, the most likely reasons are that you have a memory leak or you simply have a near-real-time system with insufficient capacity to process the load you are experiencing.  A leak might be due to the usual suspects, e.g. not detaching event handlers which you can diagnose with memory profilers, but we'll rule that out for now.

If you must keep up with quotes as they are updated, they have to go somewhere such as a queue or be dispatched to a thread, and unless you can keep up, this can grow unbounded.

The only way to solve this problem is to:

- throw some quotes on the floor
- get beefier hardware
- process quotes more efficiently

I think you are hoping that there is a clear alternative to process quotes more efficiently with a new data structure or algorithm that could make a big difference.  But even if you do make it more efficient, the problem could still come back and you may be forced to consider gracefully degrading under overload conditions rather than failing with out of memory.

But in general terms, for high performance simpler is often better and fewer threads swaps is better.  For example, if the work done in update is small, making it synchronous could be a big win, even though it seems counter intuitive.  You have to know what the update handler does and most of all for a near-real-time system you have to measure, measure, measure to empirically know which is fastest.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: @Chris: You may not agree with my answer, but my answer is that he has not given us enough information to answer the question directly.  I've also suggested an alternative design strategy.

Comment: It's really simple. Quote class library provides a AddSybmol method, once AddSymbol is called throws update events which tells you which symbol has changed. Also provides GetCell method to get the quote field needed. My trading strategy classes which are quote observers need to know exactly which cell gets updated. This is what I do in the background threads, call GetCell on the fields, check the fields against what I have stored as the previous quote, update what's changed and notify the observer classes. The order class library works the same. Let me know if this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

To me

> I currently have the callbacks execute in the thread pool

and

> Once observers are notified the background thread dies

are mildly contradictory. I suspect you might be intending to use threads from a pool, but accidentally using new 'free' (unpooled) threads each time.

You might want to look at the documentation for [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx).

However, I suggest you use a profiler/perfmon to find the resource leak first and foremost. Replacing the whole shebang with a queuing approach sounds reasonable, but it's pretty close to what you'd have anyway with a proper threadpool.

Comment: Sorry, the first callback which executes on the threadpool is the callback from the class library not my callback notifying my observer classes. This class library is not my code. It sends a notification each time there's an update say in the quote of IBM and then I have to use the GetCell method of the library to check the quote fields of IBM to see what has changed. Then I call my observer classes to notify them of the change.

Comment: No chance I have WeakReference since the only objects I am calling are the two class libraries and the observers which are initialized at the beginning and live throughout the program's execution.